# Not getting List results in VF Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, rest-api

My requirement is like when i type the 4th character in search input box, i need to implement autosuggestion and the values for which is returned as a JSON response from web service. I am able to see the response(list of records) in debug logs, but not able to get the list results in vf page using `<apex:repeat>`. Below is my code:

```
<div class="centerContent search-bar" id="id1">
<input type="text" placeholder="Start your search here.." name="srch-term" id="srch-term"/>
                                <div class="searchListCust" id="searchId">
                                <apex:outputPanel id="divId">
                                    <apex:repeat value="{!queriesList}" var="autoSuggestRec" id="listId">
                                    <div class="autoSuggestionDiv" onclick="autoSuggestionClicked(this)" id="id3">
                                    <apex:outputText value="{!autoSuggestRec.query}" escape="false" id="id4" />
                                    </div>
                                    </apex:repeat>
                                 </apex:outputPanel>
                                </div>

                            </div>    <script>

// input field enter: trigger the search button click run the search method
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".searchListCust").hide();
    $("#srch-term").keyup(function(){
            if($("#srch-term").val().length > 3){
            alert('typing after 3');
            //call action function
            var autoSuggestionInput = $("#srch-term").val();

            $(".searchListCust").show();
            alert('autoSuggestionInput ----'+autoSuggestionInput);
            autoSuggestion(autoSuggestionInput);
        }
    });
/*
    $(".search-bar span .autoSuggestionDiv").on("click",function(){
            $("#srch-term").val(this.innerText);
            $(".searchListCust").hide();
            // autosearch
            searchBtnClicked();
    });*/
});
function autoSuggestionClicked(el) {
    $("#srch-term").val(el.innerText);
            $(".searchListCust").hide();
            // autosearch
            searchBtnClicked();
}
</script>
```

Controller Class :

```
public PageReference autoCompleteCustom(){
    system.debug('In auto suggest controller');
    system.debug('autoSuggestedValue======='+autoSuggestedValue);


   queriesList = new List<Queries>();
    try{
   HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
   req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
   req.setHeader('Content-type','application/json;charset=utf-8');
   req.setEndpoint('callout:SharePointAutoSuggestUrl'+'?querysuggest='+'%27'+autoSuggestedValue+'%27');
   req.setMethod('GET');
   Http http = new Http();
   HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
  // if(res.getstatusCode() == 200 && res.getbody() != null){

   system.debug('respose body-----'+res.getBody());
   Map<string,Object> deserializedMap = (map<string,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());

    List<Object> autoQueryList = (List<Object>)deserializedMap.get('Queries');
    system.debug('autoQueryList ='+autoQueryList);
    if(autoQueryList != null && autoQueryList.size()>0){
        for(Object autoQueryRec :autoQueryList ){
            Map<String,object> autoQueryMap = (Map<String,object>)autoQueryRec;
            Queries autoSuggestRec = new Queries(autoQueryMap);
            system.debug('autoSuggestRec ='+autoSuggestRec.query);
           queriesList.add(autoSuggestRec);
           system.debug('queryList==='+queriesList);

        }
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e){ 

    }
    return null;
}

public class Queries{
    public boolean isPersonal{get;set;}
    public string query{get;set;}
    public Queries(map<string,object> QueriesLocal){
        isPersonal = (boolean)QueriesLocal.get('IsPersonal');
        query = (String)QueriesLocal.get('Query');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented this in the past using far less javascript.

Check it out:

```
public class ExternalSearchController{

    public List<Queries> searchResults {get; set;}
    public String searchString {get; set;}

    public void performSearch(){
        searchResults = new List<Queries>();
        if (String.isNotBlank(searchString) && searchString.replaceAll(' ','').length() > 3) {
            try{
                HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
                req.setHeader('Accept','application/json');
                req.setHeader('Content-type','application/json;charset=utf-8');
                req.setEndpoint('callout:SharePointAutoSuggestUrl'+'?querysuggest='+'%27'+searchString+'%27');
                req.setMethod('GET');
                Http http = new Http();
                HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
                if(res.getstatusCode() == 200 && res.getbody() != null){

                    system.debug('respose body----->'+res.getBody());
                    Map<string,Object> deserializedMap = (map<string,Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
                    List<Object> autoQueryList = (List<Object>)deserializedMap.get('Queries');
                    if(autoQueryList != null && autoQueryList.size()>0){
                        for(Object autoQueryRec :autoQueryList ){
                            Map<String,object> autoQueryMap = (Map<String,object>)autoQueryRec;
                            Queries autoSuggestRec = new Queries(autoQueryMap);
                            searchResults.add(autoSuggestRec);

                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (exception e){
                system.debug('Something went wrong... '+e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Queries{
        public boolean isPersonal{get;set;}
        public string query{get;set;}
        public Queries(map<string,object> QueriesLocal){
            isPersonal = (boolean)QueriesLocal.get('IsPersonal');
            query = (String)QueriesLocal.get('Query');
        }
    }    
}
```

Visualforce:

```
    <apex:page  docType="html-5.0">
    <script>
    </script>
    <apex:slds ></apex:slds>
    <div class="slds-scope">
        <apex:form >
            <apex:inputText value="{!searchString}" styleclass="slds-input" id="table-search" onkeyup="getResults();" html-placeholder="Search"/>
            <apex:actionFunction name="getResults" action="{!performSearch}" reRender="thetable"/>
            <apex:outputPanel id="thetable">
                <table class="slds-table slds-table--bordered slds-table--cell-buffer slds-no-row-hover">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="slds-text-title--caps">
                            <th scope="col" class="slds-cell-wrap">
                                <div class="slds-truncate">Is Personal</div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="slds-cell-wrap">
                                <div class="slds-truncate">Query</div>
                            </th>   
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <apex:repeat value="{!searchResults}" var="result">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="slds-cell-wrap">
                                    {!result.isPersonal}
                                </td>       
                                <td class="slds-cell-wrap">
                                    {!result.query}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </apex:repeat>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </apex:outputPanel>

        </apex:form>
    </div>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Mitch. But when i am trying to print the size of the list in vf page, i am getting the value as 0. Hence thelist is not coming up in the page is what i am guessing.

Comment: Thanks Mitch. But when i am trying to print the size of the list in vf page, its showing 0. Hence results are not coming up in vf page. {!queriesList.size} is giving me zero. Can you please tell what is wrong with my code

Comment: Can you share the response form your callout?